# How to update model in a paperclip processor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, processor

I've build a processor that determine which image format is best to compress my model attached thumbnail.  The processor simply build images in png and jpg and check which one is the smallest.

Since Paperclip use the original thumbnail format to build it's thumbnail style URL I had to create a field in my model to store the format of each of the styled thumbnail.

ex: thumbnail_small_content_type, would be "image/png"

In my processor I tried to save the format by using the Paperclip:attachment method : instance_write.

```
@attachment.instance_write "#{@style_name}_content_type", "image/#{optimised_format}"
```

Strangely it work perfectly when a create a new model, but failed to work when I use the paperclip method reprocess! to crop my image.  Any idea how I could workaround that limitation?

Comment: Ok here was my mistake, I was calling thumbnail.reprocess! in an after_update callback instead of before_update.